# find each div in ul list jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I have a modal popup which has different divs for different messages, now i want to hide each div and show just the one I need to show.  instead of writing out each div id and setting it to hidden i wanted to do a loop so i put my divs inside an UL list.  But I can't seem to figure out how to hide just the divs inside that UL list..

```
$("#panels li").each(function (i) {
        $('div').toggle();
    });

<ul id="panels">
        <li><div id="dvError" class="hiddencol">this is div 1</div></li>
        <li><div id="dvconfirm" class="hiddencol">this is div 2</div></li>
</ul>
```

for some reason when I do this it hides them but it hides every div on my page :(

Comment: `$("#panels div").hide()` no loop needed.

Comment: `$('div').toggle();` hides all divs in the page

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just do

```
$("#panels").find('div').toggle();
```

or

```
$("#panels div").toggle();
```

or if you want to keep your loop

```
$("#panels li").each(function (i) {
    $(this).find('div').toggle();
});
```

`$('div').toggle();` <-- this will toggle every div on your page

Comment: this worked great! but i did have to remove the .toggle() and use removeClass and addClass..thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Select propriate divs and operate on them:

```
$("#panels li div").each(function (i) {
   // Do some other things on them here... with this context for the current div
   $(this).toggle();
});
```

EDIT:

the same as

```
$("#panels li div").toggle();
```

Comment: Approved :D
If you need to do other operations on the divs, its possible to put them inside the each cycle.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$("#panels li").each(function (i) {
    $(this).find('div').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple

```
$('div').toggle();
```

is not related to your first selection, it simply finds every **div** on the page. Try

```
$('#panels * div').toggle();
```

instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide all the div's inside the ul list then it is just the problem with the selector. You do not need to write the loop to select the elements . Because in jQUery when you write a selector all the elements that satisfy the condition are iterated and selected..

```
   $('ul#panels div').hide();
    $('ul div').hide();
    $('ul > li div').hide();
```

All these three selectors accomplish the same thing..
The first and the second selectors are almost the same. They select all the div's which are under ul.
I prefer the third selector as it will select only the immediate children i.e, li in this case and only hide the div's inside them...

Also check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/P3xe6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Now you can pass the `id` and show only the required `div`

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    showOnlyMe('dvError');
});

function showOnlyMe(myID){
    $("#panels li div").each(function () {    
        if($(this).attr('id') != myID) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });
}
```